# Andoroid how add video and GIF in android local notification?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-video-player, android-remoteview

Is it possible too embedded video and gif player into android rich notification like iOS?

If possible, please give me an example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to use custom layouts in your notification. Check this link: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/custom-notification

Comment: @DmitriyMiyai Thank you.  Do you have some example?  
RemoteView does not support video player.

Comment: Android `Notification` objects do not support video or arbitrary widgets. It is possible that some devices running newer versions of Android might support animated GIFs by using an `ImageView` in `RemoteViews`, but I would not count on it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Tank you. I'll try to put a GIF in ImageViev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since notification is a RemoteView, where is no way to show GIF animation. Allowed only widgets that describes in official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).